# UIImageView not working in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm using this code to load an image into my UITableView.

But nothing is loading, any ideas why?  The link is correct when I NSLog it.

```
NSString *temp = [appointmentDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"patient_small_photo_url"]; 
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
cell.patientImage = myImageView;
```

Update:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"appointmentCell";

    AppointmentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *appointmentDictionaryTemp = [self.appointmentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.patientNameLabel.text = [appointmentDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"patient"];
    cell.appointmentTimeLabel.text = [appointmentDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"scheduled_time"];

    NSString *urlString = [[appointmentDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"patient_small_photo_url"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    cell.patientImage.image = image; 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the response of the request, you may not be getting image data if back.

Comment: There is a lot of code in this question, but I miss the crucial part:  What class is 'cell' of and what's its 'patientInage'

Comment: Guess cell is Nil. EDIT: Didn't see it already works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
cell.patientImage.image = image;
```

Of course you don't need to create `myImageView`.

Comment: Sorry I give you the answer without any explaination: the error you made is to assign to the imageview of the cell another imageview, instead of just set the image of the already existing view.

Comment: This worked.  But now its choppy when scrolling through the table.  I'm posting the full code in the question if you can find any way to optimize scrolling. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's because you're using dataWithContentsOfURL in a table view. You'd be better off asking that separately (or just looking it up yourself) because it's a much bigger issue.

Comment: you need to download images async. there're at least 3-4 ways to do that, from using libreries  like AFNetworking to use NSQueue...

Comment: Added question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160223/how-to-make-images-in-uitableviewcell-scroll-smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding percent escapes to your URL string.

```
NSString *urlString = [[appointmentDictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"patient_small_photo_url"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately.  The link is `https` instead of `http` if that makes a difference.

Comment: Set a breakpoint after you send the `-dataWithContentsOfURL` message and check to see what's coming over the wire. Maybe it's a problem with setting the image on the image view. How are you setting up your cell? Is `patientImage` connected to a UIImageView?